# asp.net web api custom method action type GET by id return 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i want to create new project with web api. But i have some issue when call api type GET with id. The result is page 404 but i write in the same process with request type 'POST' just different between '[HttpPost]' & '[HttpGet]'

this is my code in controller name JobsController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace TechReqApi.Controllers
{

    public class JobsController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string getJobsByRequest()
        {
            return "dasdasda";
        }

        [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [HttpGet]
        public List<mdJobReq> getJobsByRequestStatusId(int RequestStatusId)
        {
            List<mdJobReq> List_mdJobReq = new List<mdJobReq>();


            return List_mdJobReq;
        }


    }
}
```

And this is My WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors();
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
```

in my case i want to call service like format -> api/controller/action/{id}, and i tried already but still not working

Comment: Show all relevant code. I assume you just need to omit `getJobsByRequestStatusId` from your URI.

Comment: can You show us Your routeConfig? its in: App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: @CodeCaster : please check my question again

Comment: @garret : Please check my question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probobly You don't have RequestStatusId in your route,

Try to call:

```
http://localhost:52741/api/jobs?RequestStatusId=6
```

or

```
http://localhost:52741/api/jobs/getJobsByRequestStatusId?RequestStatusId=6
```

Or try to change action to

```
[HttpGet]
public List<mdJobReq> getJobsByRequestStatusId(int Id)
```

**EDIT1**

In order to add action to routing, change routeConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

then to call this request you will have to use url:

```
http://localhost:52741/api/jobs/getJobsByRequestStatusId?RequestStatusId=6
```

**edit 2**

In order to make url call like this:

```
http://localhost:52741/api/jobs/getJobsByRequestStatusId/6
```

change action too

```
[HttpGet]
public List<mdJobReq> getJobsByRequestStatusId(int Id)
```

More info about routing:
[ROUTING](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions)

Comment: In my case, i want service call like this 

/api/controller/action/{id}